# DB2 tablespaces: "partition-by-range" or "partition-by-growth"

Tags: db2, tablespace, db2-zos

During the upgrade from DB2 9 to DB2 10 on z/OS, the previous (now retired) DBA converted all tablespaces from "simple" to "universal". How can I determine if they are partition-by-range or partition-by-growth?

Using RC/Query in CA/Tools from Computer Associates, I was able to reverse-engineer the CREATE TABLESPACE statement, but it's not obvious from the code which type of tablespace this is.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE SNF101
       IN DNF1
       USING STOGROUP GNF2
           PRIQTY 48
           SECQTY 48
           ERASE NO
       BUFFERPOOL BP1
       CLOSE NO
       LOCKMAX SYSTEM
       SEGSIZE 4
       FREEPAGE 0
       PCTFREE 5
       GBPCACHE CHANGED
       DEFINE YES
       LOGGED
       TRACKMOD YES
       COMPRESS NO
       LOCKSIZE ANY
       MAXROWS 255
       CCSID EBCDIC
;
```

Given that CREATE TABLE statement, how can I determine if this is partition-by-range or partition-by-growth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your version of the CA/Tools is capable of recognizing the tablespace types and also generating the matching DDL.

Check the [SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablespacetable.html) column TYPE,  value G indicates partition-by-growth, value R indicates partition by range.

Comment: Also, refer to Table 4 of the CREATE TABLESPACE documentation to determine what type of table space your statement will result in: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtablespace.html

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!